# how to show pdf which come from server

Tags: javascript, html, angular, express

i m trying to show thumbnail in front.i used angular but when i try to show in html img tag the angular show CORB error like this Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost:8080/notes/file-1588247985539.pdf.
I try something like this

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let n of notes">
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/notes/{{ n.notes }}" target="_blank">


      <img src="http://localhost:8080/notes/{{ n.notes }}" alt="" />
    </a>
    <button (click)="downlodenotes(n.notes, 'filename')">
      <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

HTTp Service

```
 getnotes() {
    return this.http.get(`${notes}/fetch`);
  }
```

How can i resove this error

Comment: Hi.  Did you ever figure this out?  If so, can you please create a solution?